# Magento order confirmation email not receiving after cron setup 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have a magento installation https://ashoo.com.au ... All things are working fine but when a customer plces order, emails are not sending to customer not at the admin email... But orders are present in magento admin... I have searched on internet.. Here are some of the things I tried this through cpanel...

```
1. curl -s -o /dev/null https://ashoo.com.au/cron.php
2. php https://ashoo.com.au/cron.php
3. /home/ashoo/public_html/cron.ssh
```

I have put times to 1 time per minutes and 5 times per minute

Cron Job runs but no emails... Any help  would be appreciated

**Note:**
php mail function is working just fine on my server.. So I tested that which is sending me mails

Comment: Check your Magento settings, AFAIK Magento doesn't use PHP's mail method, instead it uses Zend_Mail. Also, do registration emails work, or is it just order emails?

Comment: Have you checked your server mail logs or your magento exception log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I have solved this by adding code inside successAction() method of OnepageController.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM core_email_queue_recipients INNER JOIN core_email_queue ON core_email_queue.message_id = core_email_queue_recipients.message_id WHERE event_type = 'new_order' ORDER BY core_email_queue.message_id DESC LIMIT 2";


        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');

        foreach ($connection->fetchAll($sql) as $arr_row) {
            $message_body = $arr_row['message_body'];
            $recipient_email = $arr_row['recipient_email'];
            $message_parameters = $arr_row['message_parameters'];
            $message_parameters = unserialize($message_parameters);
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

            // More headers
            $headers .= 'From: '.$message_parameters['from_name'].'<'.$message_parameters['from_email'].'>' . "\r\n";
//            $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";
            mail($recipient_email, $message_parameters['subject'], $message_body, $headers);

        }
```

Now it is sending  emails of new orders